# Is the Netgear GS305P a level 2 or level 3 switch?

Tags: networking

I bought this switch and I assume it's level 2.
But it's written nowhere. I looked into the manual and on Amazon. No information about it.

I already installed it in my home network and it's working. I am just interested if it's level 2 or 3.

On [meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76731/where-do-i-ask-hardware-related-questions) they say hardware questions can be asked here.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @John see my edit

Comment: Switch is by definition Layer 2. Some are also performing (usually limited) routing on L3 but it surely isn't a thing for simple device as GS305P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the following netgear catalog, it's a L2 switch (page 18, array on the right side in the category "Unmanaged, L2, Gigabit") :

https://www.downloads.netgear.com/files/netgear/documents/netgear-interactive-catalog_14jan21.pdf